# how to attach styled-component style to a component className props?

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

hi guys i've create a react component. in react way i could easily attach css style to my component via className="some_style"

but how do i attach my styled component to these className props.

say per as

```
<Component className="styled_component" />
```

i don't know which approach im gonna use ?
Thanks

Comment: 'Styled Components' literally means you are creating a new type of component that is styled. There is no need for styling based on classes when using Styled Components, that's the whole point. Have a read through the styled components docs, this question implies that you don't understand what styled components are or how to use them. Once you understand the general topic, if you still have a specific problem, post it on stack and we can help.

Comment: actually i understand what styled-component does. i just need to do this because some library (reactour helper) expect to provide styling through className props.:)

Comment: That is not clear from your question, please rephrase the question to make it clearer. Are you trying to add a class to a styled component? Instead of following up on every response with the real problem, explain the actual problem in the question.

Comment: If what you are trying to do is attach the style properties of a styled component to a component using classes then just don't use styled components, make a css class and use that instead.

Answer (score 3):

This usually works well for me (even if hilariously I actually found this question cause I'm having trouble with a specific situation using `className`):

```
const Component = styled.div.attrs({
  className: '[add your classes here]'
})
```

Comment: This should probably be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can't because you don't know which classname will your css-in-js gets compiled to. Styled component helps you write the CSS of a particular component in JS. You can try writing the CSS of `<Component />` in Component.js file. If the CSS class is reuseable, create a common CSS file and include it in index.js/App.js

Comment: actually its mandatory requirement for a library called reactour. which is i need to pass as style to its className props. but i prefered with styled-component way. any suggestion ? :)

Comment: Styled component also has its own methodology which won't suggest you to do so. If you come across any solution, it would be a hack. Better would be create a style.css file where you declare static classnames.

Answer (score -1):

When using styled-components, you don't have to use the `className` prop on your components anymore. Let's say you've got a div that you want to style. First declare the div as a styled-component.

```
const StyledDiv = styled.div`
   background-color: blue;
`
```

Notice how I'm using styled.**div** as it's a div element I'm using. Then to render this componenet, you do the same as you would with any other component.

```
return(
   <StyledDiv />
)
```

The div will then render with the css you applied to it, you don't have to interact with `className`.

Comment: actually its mandatory requirement for a library called reactour. which is i need to pass as style to its className props. but i prefered with styled-component way. any suggestion ? :)

Comment: Well then it would appear that you're using the wrong solution for your css. Maybe instead of declaring styled components, you should use the traditional approach of a separate css file, so you know the class names on run-time.